# Node-hid Module did not self-register on webworker

Tags: javascript, electron

I am getting this with node-hid:

> > Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.
> >         at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
> >         at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
> >         at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
> >         at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
> >         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
> >         at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
> >         at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
> >         at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
> >         at bindings (C:\Users\ferna\Documents\elantana\Clientes\Solid-Optics\CodigoFuente\WebMFTElectron\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:81:44)
> >         at loadBinding (C:\Users\ferna\Documents\elantana\Clientes\Solid-Optics\CodigoFuente\WebMFTElectron\node-hid\nodehid.js:16:38)
> >     module.(anonymous function) @ ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172
> >     Module._extensions..node @ module.js:671 module.(anonymous function) @
> >     ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172 Module.load @ module.js:561 tryModuleLoad @
> >     module.js:504 Module._load @ module.js:496 Module.require @
> >     module.js:586 require @ internal/module.js:11 bindings @
> >     C:\Users\ferna\Documents\elantana\Clientes\Solid-Optics\CodigoFuente\WebMFTElectron\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:81
> >     loadBinding @
> >     C:\Users\ferna\Documents\elantana\Clientes\Solid-Optics\CodigoFuente\WebMFTElectron\node-hid\nodehid.js:16
> >     showdevices @
> >     C:\Users\ferna\Documents\elantana\Clientes\Solid-Optics\CodigoFuente\WebMFTElectron\node-hid\nodehid.js:132
> >     scanDevices @ mft.js:26 (anonymous) @ VM130:1

The issue appears after accesing first the device in a normal javascript code and then accessing the device using the webworker. It also happens doing it the other way around.

I made a simple example just trying to retrieve the devices present

This is my javascript code:

```
nodehid = require("node-hid")
var hiddevices = new Worker('./lib/hid/hiddevices.js');

hiddevices.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var result = e.data;
    switch (result.command) {
        case HID_SCAN_DEVICES:
             console.log(result);
             break;

    }
}, false);



var usbInfo = {
    vendorId: 0x10C4,
    productId: 0xEA90,
};

/**
 * Scan the devices present at the system and filters them to match only the MFT
 * @return {Message} JSON  message
 */
function scanDevices_nww() {

    var rawDevices = nodehid.devices();
    var mftDevices = rawDevices.filter(x=>x.vendorId == usbInfo.vendorId && x.productId == usbInfo.productId);
    if(mftDevices.length > 0) {
        mftInfo.usbpath = mftDevices[0].path;
    }
}


function scanDevices_WebWorker() {
    var scanDevices_WebWorkerCommand= {
        command: HID_SCAN_DEVICES,
        params: null
    }
    hiddevices.postMessage(scanDevices_WebWorkerCommand);
}
```

And this is the code of the web worker

```
if ("function" === typeof importScripts) {

importScripts("../solid-optics/commandconsts.js");
importScripts("../hid/hidreports.js");

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var command = e.data;
    var result = null;

    switch (command.command) {        
        case HID_SCAN_DEVICES:
            result = scanDevices();
            break;
            break;
        case HID_INITIALICE:
            result = initMFT(command.params);
            break;
    }

    return self.postMessage(result);

}, false);

/**
 * Scan the devices present at the system and filters them to match only the MFT
 * @return {Message} JSON  message
 */
function scanDevices() {

    var rawDevices = nodehid.devices();
    var mftDevices = rawDevices.filter(x=>x.vendorId == usbInfo.vendorId && x.productId == usbInfo.productId);
    return {
        command: HID_SCAN_DEVICES,
        result: mftDevices.length
    }
}
```

I have this on my main.js

```
webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks when you load the node-hid library, it gets locked into the thread it has been used. To re-use it you need to unload the libary and load it again.

I decided to move everything into the main thread and, instead of using webworkers, use promises.